# How can I remove slash in route of controller?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

Here is my code:

```
[Route("{culture}-Index.html")]
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Now if my culture is en-us, the URL will match `en-us-Index.html`.

However, I want the URL match this:
`enus-Index.html`

As you see, removing the slash in the `culture`.

How can I achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: URL re-writing may help. [Refer Link](you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to use culture parameter with te MapApiRoute overload.

More details, you could refer to below example codes:

```
    [Route("{culture:regex(^[[a-zA-Z]]{{4}}-index.html$)}")]

    public IActionResult Index()
    {

   
        return View(new CreateEmployeeViewModelData { Gender= Gender.Male });
    }
```

Result:

[image]